# sendmail not working

Tags: email, opensuse, sendmail, smtp

I have a website where mails are sent. Those mails from website (contact mail, booking mail) are being sent well. But when I go to shell with ssh and give `sendmail myemail@mail.com` it is not sending.

the error log in `/var/log/mail` says:

```
did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
```

some time ago, i had a problem with permission, i changed without knowing the permission of `/etc/` folder, then later i did `chmod 755 /etc/` then everything seemed to work properly. but now, i am getting this error.

server os is openSuse.

what can I do?

Comment: What if you try `mail myemail@mail.com` instead of `sendmail`?

Comment: @derobert i am getting this message if i give mail: ``If 'mail' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf mail
``

Comment: @derobert and i gave with ``cnf`` but nothing happened. neither error message nor email was sent

Answer (score 7):

Try the following test command/script

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -v -- myemail@mail.com <<END
subject: test

test
END
```

Comment: for anyone who didn't find this answer useful: read carefully the output. for me it wasn't obvious what it is about, but reading more carefully it revealed this link: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131?visit_id=638043818293733488-3941945688&p=UnsolicitedMessageError&rd=1

Answer (score 2):

[You can install the mail package in Ubuntu with below command.](http://gotechnies.com/mail-command/)

For Ubuntu -:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y mailutils
```

For CentOs-:

```
$ sudo yum install -y mailx
```

Test Mail command-:

```
$ echo "Mail test" | mail -s "Subject" youremail@domain.com
```